# axis text rotation inside group in d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I'm working on developing a bar chart using d3.js. Where i'm willing to rotate x-axis text with 10 degree angle. i'm applying text rotation as:

```
    g.selectAll("barbasetext2")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .attr("class","barbasetext2")
   .text(function(d) {
        return d.NumberName; 
   })
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.FullName) + (x.rangeBand()/2); 
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
        return (height - margin.bottom) + 35 ;
   })
   .attr("transform","rotate(10)") //Applying rotation here
   .attr("font-family", textfontfamily) 
   .attr("font-size", textfontsize)
   .attr("fill", textfontcolor);
```

According to my knowledge, text should be rotate, but here the complete group is rotating. here is the complete code sample:

```css
html,body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:none; padding:none; }
#barchart { width:95%; height:95%; margin:none; padding:none; }

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.1.10/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="barchart" />
<script>

var  elementid = "#barchart"; //div id here
var  textfontfamily = "sans-serif";
var  textfontsize = "11px";
var  textfontcolor = "black";
var  roundedcornerradius = 6;
var  baranimationduration = 500; //set it '0' to disable animation


var     margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 30};
var     width = $(elementid).innerWidth()  - margin.left - margin.right;
var     height = $(elementid).innerHeight() - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var  middlemarginw = 15;
var  middlemarginh = 15;

data = [
  {FullName: "A1", NumberName: "NA1", Seconds: 571200},
  {FullName: "A2", NumberName: "NA2", Seconds: 571200},
  {FullName: "A3", NumberName: "NA3", Seconds: 571200},
  {FullName: "A4", NumberName: "NA4", Seconds: 571200},
  {FullName: "A5", NumberName: "NA5", Seconds: 571200},
  {FullName: "A6", NumberName: "NA6", Seconds: 571200},
  {FullName: "A7", NumberName: "NA7", Seconds: 568896},
  {FullName: "A8", NumberName: "NA8", Seconds: 568896},
  {FullName: "A9", NumberName: "NA9", Seconds: 568896},
  {FullName: "A10",NumberName: "NA10", Seconds: 568896}
];


var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
 .rangeRoundBands([margin.left + middlemarginw, width - middlemarginw], .1, .42);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height - margin.bottom , margin.top + margin.bottom]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y);
 yAxis.orient("left");
 
 
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.FullName; }));
y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.Seconds - 1000; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Seconds; })]);


var svg = d3.select(elementid).append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%");

var g = svg.append("g");
     g.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ")"); 

 
 //Create Y-AXIS
 g.append("g") 
      .attr("class", "y axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left + margin.right + margin.left + middlemarginw) + ")")
      .call(yAxis)
   .selectAll('text')
   .text(function(d) {
   return d;
  })
   .attr("font-family", textfontfamily) 
   .attr("font-size", textfontsize)
   .attr("fill", textfontcolor);

   function rectangle(x, y, width, height, radius){
  return "M" + (x + radius) + "," + y + "h" + (width - 2*radius) + "a" + radius + "," + radius + " 0 0 1 " + radius + "," + radius + "v" + (height - 2*radius) + "v" + radius + "h" + -radius + "h" + (2*radius - width) + "h" + -radius + "v" + -radius + "v" + (2*radius - height) + "a" + radius + "," + radius + " 0 0 1 " + radius + "," + -radius + "z";
  };

 //Create Bars
 g.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
   .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "bar")
   .attr("d", function(d){return rectangle(x(d.FullName),height - margin.bottom, x.rangeBand(),0,5);} )
      .style({fill: "red"})
   .transition()
  .duration(baranimationduration)
  .ease("linear")
  .attr("d", function(d){return rectangle(x(d.FullName),y(d.Seconds), x.rangeBand(),height - y(d.Seconds) - margin.bottom,roundedcornerradius);} )
  .style("fill", "orange")
  .style("opacity", "1");
   
  //Create Bars base text  1
 g.selectAll("barbasetext1")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class","barbasetext1")
    .text(function(d) {
   return d.FullName; //whatever u wanna display here
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
   return x(d.FullName) + (x.rangeBand()/2); //will be d.FullName here bcoz x-axis is binded with it.
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
   return (height - margin.bottom) +  20 ;
    })
    .attr("font-family", textfontfamily) 
    .attr("font-size", textfontsize)
    .attr("fill", textfontcolor);

    
 //Create Bars base text  2
 g.selectAll("barbasetext2")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class","barbasetext2")
    .text(function(d) {
   return d.NumberName; 
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
   return x(d.FullName) + (x.rangeBand()/2); 
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
   return (height - margin.bottom) + 35 ;
    })
    .attr("transform","rotate(10)")
    .attr("font-family", textfontfamily) 
    .attr("font-size", textfontsize)
    .attr("fill", textfontcolor);
 
    
 //Create X-AXIS line
 g.append("line")          
  .style("stroke", "black")  
  .attr("x1", margin.left + middlemarginw + margin.left + margin.right )
  .attr("y1", (height - margin.bottom)+5)     
  .attr("x2", width - margin.right - margin.left - middlemarginw)     
  .attr("y2", (height - margin.bottom)+5) ;  

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because `rotate` actually rotates around the origin (0,0) of the coordinate system (unless you set the center of rotate).

There are several alternatives to fix this. One of them is setting the `x` and `y` position of the text in the same `transform`:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + (x(d.FullName) + (x.rangeBand() / 2)) + "," +
        ((height - margin.bottom) + 35) + ") rotate(10)"
})
```

Here is your updated code:

```css
html,body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:none; padding:none; }
#barchart { width:95%; height:95%; margin:none; padding:none; }

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.1.10/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="barchart" />
<script>

var  elementid = "#barchart"; //div id here
var  textfontfamily = "sans-serif";
var  textfontsize = "11px";
var  textfontcolor = "black";
var  roundedcornerradius = 6;
var  baranimationduration = 500; //set it '0' to disable animation


var     margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 30};
var     width = $(elementid).innerWidth()  - margin.left - margin.right;
var     height = $(elementid).innerHeight() - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var  middlemarginw = 15;
var  middlemarginh = 15;

data = [
  {FullName: "A1", NumberName: "NA1", Seconds: 571200},
  {FullName: "A2", NumberName: "NA2", Seconds: 571200},
  {FullName: "A3", NumberName: "NA3", Seconds: 571200},
  {FullName: "A4", NumberName: "NA4", Seconds: 571200},
  {FullName: "A5", NumberName: "NA5", Seconds: 571200},
  {FullName: "A6", NumberName: "NA6", Seconds: 571200},
  {FullName: "A7", NumberName: "NA7", Seconds: 568896},
  {FullName: "A8", NumberName: "NA8", Seconds: 568896},
  {FullName: "A9", NumberName: "NA9", Seconds: 568896},
  {FullName: "A10",NumberName: "NA10", Seconds: 568896}
];


var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
 .rangeRoundBands([margin.left + middlemarginw, width - middlemarginw], .1, .42);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height - margin.bottom , margin.top + margin.bottom]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y);
 yAxis.orient("left");
 
 
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.FullName; }));
y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.Seconds - 1000; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Seconds; })]);


var svg = d3.select(elementid).append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%");

var g = svg.append("g");
     g.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ")"); 

 
 //Create Y-AXIS
 g.append("g") 
      .attr("class", "y axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left + margin.right + margin.left + middlemarginw) + ")")
      .call(yAxis)
   .selectAll('text')
   .text(function(d) {
   return d;
  })
   .attr("font-family", textfontfamily) 
   .attr("font-size", textfontsize)
   .attr("fill", textfontcolor);

   function rectangle(x, y, width, height, radius){
  return "M" + (x + radius) + "," + y + "h" + (width - 2*radius) + "a" + radius + "," + radius + " 0 0 1 " + radius + "," + radius + "v" + (height - 2*radius) + "v" + radius + "h" + -radius + "h" + (2*radius - width) + "h" + -radius + "v" + -radius + "v" + (2*radius - height) + "a" + radius + "," + radius + " 0 0 1 " + radius + "," + -radius + "z";
  };

 //Create Bars
 g.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
   .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "bar")
   .attr("d", function(d){return rectangle(x(d.FullName),height - margin.bottom, x.rangeBand(),0,5);} )
      .style({fill: "red"})
   .transition()
  .duration(baranimationduration)
  .ease("linear")
  .attr("d", function(d){return rectangle(x(d.FullName),y(d.Seconds), x.rangeBand(),height - y(d.Seconds) - margin.bottom,roundedcornerradius);} )
  .style("fill", "orange")
  .style("opacity", "1");
   
  //Create Bars base text  1
 g.selectAll("barbasetext1")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class","barbasetext1")
    .text(function(d) {
   return d.FullName; //whatever u wanna display here
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
   return x(d.FullName) + (x.rangeBand()/2); //will be d.FullName here bcoz x-axis is binded with it.
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
   return (height - margin.bottom) +  20 ;
    })
    .attr("font-family", textfontfamily) 
    .attr("font-size", textfontsize)
    .attr("fill", textfontcolor);

    
 //Create Bars base text  2
 g.selectAll("barbasetext2")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class","barbasetext2")
    .text(function(d) {
   return d.NumberName; 
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d){
     return "translate(" + (x(d.FullName) + (x.rangeBand()/2) - 12) + "," + ((height - margin.bottom) + 35) + ") rotate(10)"})
    .attr("font-family", textfontfamily) 
    .attr("font-size", textfontsize)
    .attr("fill", textfontcolor);
 
    
 //Create X-AXIS line
 g.append("line")          
  .style("stroke", "black")  
  .attr("x1", margin.left + middlemarginw + margin.left + margin.right )
  .attr("y1", (height - margin.bottom)+5)     
  .attr("x2", width - margin.right - margin.left - middlemarginw)     
  .attr("y2", (height - margin.bottom)+5) ;  

</script>
```

Comment: Ok Thanks for the solution. You mean 'g' coordinates are 0,0 and that's why all texts are rotating accordingly?

Comment: Yes, they all rotate according to the top left corner of the user coordinate system: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform